# Modifying state with response from backend express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm pretty new to development, and I could use some guidance. I'm trying to serve up data from my back end after retrieving it from an external API, which works in terms of being able to view the response data in the console/back end. However when I modify my state in React and attempt to use that data on the front end the state is still undefined/an empty string.

Both servers are running on different ports and are communicating properly.

App.js (Front end)

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      apiResponse: '',
      products: ''
    };
  }

  // Fetch a varying API route based on the argument
  callAPI(x) {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/" + x)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse }))

      .catch(err => err);
  }

<Button
    onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); this.callAPI('api') }}
    type="success"
    className="input-lg">
    Records
</Button>
```

api.js (Back end)

```
router.get('/api', function (req, res) {
   axios.get('https://.......................',  config)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is your component's `render` function?

Comment: And how are you attempting to use your `state`?

Comment: @ethane I want to use the data from the api call to fill a table ultimately. I have tried all of the comments below and I still can't seem to adjust the state. The render second just has a return and a button that uses the callAPI function onClick, which works because I get a response in the console.

Comment: Besides your api not sending a reponse to the caller, are you getting any front-end compile errors?

Answer (score 0):

Do you already try work with a redirect response?

It's like that:

```
    return axios.get('https://.......................',  config)
         .then((resp) => {
            const url = "http://<yourfront:yourport>/"
                    .concat("?yourData="+resp.data);
            res.location(url.toString());
            res.status(301);
            res.end();
            return;
         })
        .catch((error) => {
           console.log(error);
        });
```

So, when front receives this response, the framework knows it needs to change himself state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `callAPI` in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    apiResponse: '',
    products: ''
  };

  this.callAPI = this.callAPI.bind(this); // bind callAPI

}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html